# Why is bernoulli_distribution::param_type's constructor explicit?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, libstdc++

In §26.5.1.6/7 it says:

> It is unspecified whether `D::param_type` is declared as a (nested)
>   class or via a typedef. In this subclause 26.5, declarations of
>   `D::param_type` are in the form of typedefs for convenience of
>   exposition only.

This seems to indicate that the `param_type` is implementation defined. In particular for GCC and Clang, the following does not compile:

```
std::bernoulli_distribution d(0.50);
d.param(0.25);
```

But for MSVC 2013 it does. Looking in random.h for libstdc++, it shows that `param_type`'s constructor is marked explicit:

```
struct param_type
{
  typedef bernoulli_distribution distribution_type;

  explicit
  param_type(double __p = 0.5)
  : _M_p(__p)
  {
_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_ASSERT((_M_p >= 0.0) && (_M_p <= 1.0));
  }

  double
  p() const
  { return _M_p; }

  friend bool
  operator==(const param_type& __p1, const param_type& __p2)
  { return __p1._M_p == __p2._M_p; }

private:
  double _M_p;
};
```

thus not allowing the code above to compile.

What reason would they choose to make the constructor explicit?

Comment: _"What reason would they choose to make the constructor explicit?"_ - to prevent implicit conversions which are usually not obvious to the developer.

Comment: `d.param(decltype(d)::param_type(0.25))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the following paragraph in the specification (following on the quote above); C++ § 26.5.1.6/9:

> For each of the constructors of `D` taking arguments corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a **corresponding constructor subject to the same requirements** and taking arguments identical in number, type, and default values. Moreover, for each of the member functions of `D` that return values corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding member function with the identical name, type, and semantics.

Where;

- `P` is the embedded `param_type` and
- `D` is the random number distribution.

And given (§ 26.5.8.3.1);

```
explicit bernoulli_distribution(double p = 0.5);
```

It can be argued that the requirements of the constructor of `bernoulli_distribution` are:

- explicit construction from a single parameter
- that single parameter is of type `double`
- the parameter has a default argument of `0.5`

Thus the embedded `param_type` should be the same since they would then have *"the same requirements"* as dictated by § 26.5.1.6/9. Giving it the form;

```
explicit param_type(double __p = 0.5) { /*...*/ }
```

Although admittedly I think this may not initially be very clear in the wording. I suspect that the libstdc++ implementation has a more accurate interpretation of the specification and the MSVC implementation may be incorrect.

**Update**

Microsoft have reportedly fixed this, look out for the *VS 14 RTM* when it becomes available.